# How do I make a command with the length of how many arguments are in the command?

Tags: javascript, eval

This may sound weirdly phrased, but I don't know how else to describe it. I'm trying to make a discord bot with a command where certain people can write javascript code to do things with the bot on the fly, but I don't know how to make it work with multiple spaces. I want it to work with as many spaces as possible or as little spaces as possible, but this only works with ones with exactly 10 spaces.

```
if(command === '!cmd') {
    if(message.author.id != ownerid) {
        bot.guilds.get(guildid).channeks.get(generalchan.sned("YOU ARE NOT ALLOWED TO USE THIS COMMAND\nTHIS IS YOUR ONLY WARNING"))
        } else if(message.author.id === ownerid) {
            eval(messageArray[1] + " " + messageArray[2] + " " + messageArray[3] + " " + messageArray[4] + " " + messageArray[5] + " " + messageArray[6] + " " + messageArray[7] + " " + messageArray[8] + " " + messageArray[9]);
            message.delete();
        }
}
```

Comment: `messgeArray.join(" ")`?

Comment: This doesn't seem to have worked, I tried it but now it's giving me unhandeled promise rejections. --EDIT Seems that now it's doing eval with the !cmd, so it's basically putting !cmd before each command making it invalid.

Comment: Will need more context to understand the question. I have no idea what `meesageArray` contains and what is the expected behavior.

Comment: messageArray is the messages content split into an array using `message.content.split(" ");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Let evalStr = ""
For(let element of messageArray){
evalStr += element + " "
}
eval(evalStr)
```

You'll need to slice out the trailing space character.

But you're taking message.content then splitting each word into an array. Then trying to fuse the array back together adding the spaces back in. You should just delete the first x chars of message. content where x is prefix.length + command and eval the result.

Eval commands are very dangerous. Please make sure you know what you're doing before implementing these.

EDIT: This guide is worth taking a look at and bookmarking.

https://anidiotsguide.gitbooks.io/discord-js-bot-guide/examples/command-with-arguments.html

Comment: I have done the precautions to not allow other people other than myself use the !cmd command so no need to worry, but I also don't know how to remove parts of a string (I'm pretty new to javascript) so if you could explain this to me that'd be great

Comment: If you look up where you've defined command. You've already done this. This guide is worth bookmarking and taking a look at. Work your way through the entire gitbook. Once you've finished that, everything should be much easier. https://anidiotsguide.gitbooks.io/discord-js-bot-guide/examples/command-with-arguments.html

Please don't forget to choose a correct answer to your question.